# Closing questions that show no effort - official policy?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons

I can't figure out what I think about this. Again (https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/351591/1) someone just copied and pasted a question without showing any work at all. There is nothing about what exactly the OP is having problems with. The style of posting screams "Do my homework!".

I usually don't vote to close these questions because I can't find the right reason for closing. Questions like this are (usually) not *off topic*, not *not a real question*, not *not constructive*, etc. I did vote to close the above mentioned question. But I can't find reason to do this with the FAQ: https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#close.

Again, I don't know what to think about it and I know that the topic has come up several times in the past. But I wanted to suggest that we have at least an official policy on how to deal with this type of questions. Maybe there should be an official closing reason for this type of questions. After the question is closed for this reason, a note could be added saying that the OP can edit the question and provide provide at least a few thoughts on the question and then it can be reopened. Maybe the requirement could be that the questioner simply state what part of the question is a problem, or something.

I like that math.SE is so accessible and that it is easy to ask questions. I don't want to scare people away by being mean. I don't want to have policies that are impossible to enforce. I want to help people understand and I also want to help people with their homework.

So, could we have an *official* way of dealing with this?

And, if so, what should that policy be?

*Could we at least specify that closing a question because it doesn't show any effort is a valid closing reason?* If not, then I guess that I would want to vote to reopen the above mentioned question.

Could we add something to the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#close) so that one can add a comment with a link to something official?

I am aware of (among others)

1. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/a-consolidated-homework-policy
2. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/what-do-we-do-with-users-who-post-numerous-unlabeled-homework-questions

Comment: Please keep in mind that there is a wide spectrum of usage of the site. On one extreme we have users who like to engage in serious teaching. On the other end of the spectrum are users who strive to write answers that are "proofs from the book", and to collect and organize such beautiful proofs on this site. The latter type of usage requires no work to be shown in questions. Of course many users engage in both activities at various times. For the site to prosper, it would be best if none of these usage modes were restricted in any way (lest it alienate valued contributors).

Comment: @MathGems, thanks for posting that.

Comment: @MathGems: These people can also formulate their questions better than copy-paste from books. For example, by adding a short explanation that they seek proofs for one reason or another.

Comment: People can do lots of things in alternative ways, some of which you might define as "better" (and I would define as "often worse" in the case under discussion), but that does not nullify MathGems' observation.

Comment: @Thomas I've add TeX to that particular question, so you might want to change your link so that it points to the [first version](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/351591/1) of that post. I think it is good to go easier on the newbies and help them learn how to use the site; but in this case the closure is definitely appropriate; no real question was given there.

Comment: Just for general sake of clarity, both the linked threads are from a year ago and two years ago (respectively, at time of commenting). The site has grown a lot since then, and whatever is in there need not be *as* relevant as it was back then.

Comment: @MathGems: The last sentence of your comment is rather contentious. And the parenthetical suggests two glaring omissions with the train of thought: the first is that the permissive approach also suffers the problem of alienating (or otherwise repulsing) valued contributors, and the second is that there are things to be valued other than the quantity of valued contributors.

Comment: @Hurkyl You were not here in the initial year of the site when there was a more aggressive closing policy - which caused many problems. If the volume of questions is overwhelming to some then the correct fix is to develop better tools to deal with that volume (better filters, feeds, etc), not to censor classes of questions that are of little interest to users on one end of the spectrum.

Comment: I am leaning towards becoming more aggressive towards these question than I have in the past. Unfortunately I cannot completely filter out my annoyance about people piling up tens of thousands of rep by doing HW for freshmen. As that is clearly a wrong reason to base such a policy shift on, I will refrain from taking the lead here.

Comment: @MathGems: What sort of closings? What sorts of problems? And why would revising policy have those same problems? And would they actually be problems today?

Comment: @MathGems: I am somewhat skeptical about the ability for software to effectively filter copy/paste homework questions (henceforth cphq) but not other homework questions. But volume isn't the only issue; users who post cphq without resistance will continue to post cphq. Users who see others posting cphq -- especially upvoted cphq -- will also post cphq.

Comment: Some people were attracted here by a site whose focus is things like "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems", "Hints on mathematical problems", "History and development of mathematics", "Solving mathematical puzzles", or "Software that mathematicians use". The prevalence of cphq, however, shifts the focus away from these things and towards MSE being an on-demand answer service. I find this rather displeasing.

Comment: I also find it unethical; seeing cphq offends my sense of integrity, and seeing complete answers provided in response triggers feelings of righteous outrage that a site I frequent and care about is engaged in such activity.

Comment: In fact, if one were to believe the FAQ, one would get the impression that the *official* policy is *already* that cphq is off-topic.

Comment: I *strongly agree* with your second and third comments, @Hurkyl, and partially with the fourth. I do think that extended and well-explained solutions can be very useful, but I do agree that just writing out a solution (as if the answerer would submit a homework assignment on their own) is *usually* not the best reply.

Comment: @Hurkyl: There is nothing intrinsically unethical about cphq. A specific instance may be, but unless you can prove that you’re a long-distance mindreader, you’ve no business painting them all with that brush.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't think there is a good solution to this problem given the current SE platform. In a better-designed system one could vote on all sorts of objects, such as aspects of posts: how conceptual they are, etc, and one could filter posts based on feature rankings from *peers* (since what is conceptual or interesting to a student differs from that of an expert). That would be difficult to do on SE2.0, unless one highly overloaded tags (a big kludge).

Comment: @Brian: Nor do you have any business painting them all with the opposite brush. What we ***do*** have business doing is judging posts based on their content, and posts looks like it's demanding answers, it should be treated as such. I have no problem with words explaining how to better ask questions, but I do have a problem drinking the poison along with the punch because of some fear of offending someone who insists on posting like their cheating and can't understand why others infer as such.

Comment: @Hurkyl, there are plenty of sites devoted to the interests you listed.  What this one has is the first with a *smooth interface with easy LaTeX input!* That's it, the whole miracle, and people who can answer the hard questions did not come here for (nor from) all the Stackoverflow/SE2 community jazz or any particular values and integrity.  For as long as MathOverflow and MSE are the only game in town with good LaTeX, experts will be attracted to it.  Once that is copied, there will be forums with higher and lower degrees of compatibility with your interests and values. Now it's a hodgepodge.

Comment: (cont.)  Which implies all sorts of difficulty, and near-total pointlessness, in trying to teach or impose whatever you consider to be integrity, on the site.

Comment: As an example for @BrianM.Scott 's point, today I casually answered what could have been a CPHQ, from a low-rep anonymous user.  The OP asked for more details (another possible CPHQ indicator)... and then wrote back later with his own, better example that he had constructed "after heavy calculation".  *I* learned something from his example.  This seems like a successful use of the software for everyone involved, but would Hurkyl propose that the question be immediately WHYTed and closed as "low effort"?  Question at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352392/order-of-growth-of-derivatives

Comment: @Hurkyl: I’m not painting them with the opposite brush. I’m saying that they are to be presumed innocent until proved guilty (and that even then there’s often no harm in being generous if one happens to be in a generous mood).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, despite all the recent commotion, in which the 1-year ago thread with JDH's famous answer on homework has been cited many times to hundreds of page views, that answer got only one new downvote.  I know because I was the first to cite it recently, when it was at 50 up, 5 down.  The banning of the homework tag and of WhatHaveYouTried comments on StackOverflow may be more recent than one year and are important because in some ways SO  is an indication of MSE future.

Comment: @zyx: I never said it's irrelevant, and being pretty much the only point of visible consensus about homework problems, it will certainly be cited often. I only said that given the fact that the thread itself is quite old by now, it's time to reevaluate. In my opinion, questions which seem effortless should be closed. Closure is easily reversible, it's not the huge deal people make out of it. If it is accompanied by non-offending comments requesting improvements, those who seek deep answers will stay; those seeking something to copy to their notebooks will leave, or stay and actually learn.

Comment: Closure is sometimes reversible, but not easily reversible.

Comment: @Brian: You're not simply presuming them innocent -- you are using your presumption of innocence as a reason to dismiss probable cause to the contrary. And quite frankly, "It looked wrong, but I couldn't prove it for sure therefore I assumed it was fine and did it anyways" is not *ethical*.

Comment: @zyx: The question you linked doesn't meet my standards to be cphq, especially my conservative ones. The question is (IMO) phrased as if it were the intellectual curiosity of the questioner and something he's genuinely wondering about.

Comment: @zyx: With the "request for reopen votes" thread, reopening is really not that of a big deal. In addition one reopen vote puts the question in the review page, which is often monitored. If a proper edit has been made, I am certain five people to cast reopen votes will easily be found.

Comment: @zyx: JDH's post is, in my mind, actually irrelevant to this thread. He's advocating for students who are actually trying to participate in their own learning process; asking questions, studying answers, and the sort. However, in a large fraction of the posts that fall under the category (that I believe is) being discussed here, the poster hasn't even be bothered to *ask a question*!

Comment: The comment threads read together with JDH's answer make it clear that he specifically included cut-and-paste homework postings (note the first comments under that answer and the words "posts in the imperative") in his upvoted message denying that any homework issue exists for MSE. I think he was quite aware that some students will use the answers less wisely than others. (@Hurkyl )

Comment: There are some gigantic assumptions involved in the idea that answering homework is unethical.  If anyone cares to spell it out instead of using words like *cheating* as a thought-stopping magic amulet, I think it would be a productive (separate) thread.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Damned right I am: anything else **would** be unethical. I refuse to pretend that I’m a mindreader, and I’m appalled by the hyper-suspicious attitudes and punitive behavior of some folks here.

Comment: @zyx: JDH never says *anything* about posting in the imperative. *At best* one might construe his first comment as replying to the addendum to Yuval's comment rather than just its primary content about unwilling students. But I think it's unlikely that was his actual intent -- all of JDH's words read as someone talking about an ideal, rather than someone acknowledging and addressing the fact that the real world is sometimes less-than-ideal.

Comment: And while ideals are often wonderful things, they can become very harmful when they get invoked as thought-stopping magic amulets in an attempt to shut down discussion about things that are less-than-ideal. :p

Comment: @Brian: You appear to have very strange notions both about how one should respond to signs something questionable going on (ignore them; one should never investigate suspicions unless you already know what the result of investigation would be), and about what constitutes ethical behavior (it's ethical to assist someone, no matter how questionable it may seem, so long as you don't have proof it would be unethical... and in such a situation you don't even have a burden to straighten things out before you assist). I doubt we can resolve our disagreement.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I see nothing strange about a preference for giving people the benefit of the doubt. I see nothing admirable about jumping on newcomers or jumping to conclusions about their motives. And I see nothing admirable in attacking a straw man: I quite often do ask for clarification, and when I really do have serious qualms about a question, I either ignore it or post a skimpier hint than usual.

Comment: @Brian: At some point, I have to give up presuming there are some hidden reasonable motives and go with what a person is actually saying. When you, e.g., repeatedly tell me that one should not take any actions in regard to something I believe appears questionable on the grounds that I am not a mind reader and do not know anything's going on, eventually I have to believe that's what you actually mean. It may be a straw man, but it's not one that *I*'ve set up. If you mean something else, care to say so? (giving you that chance is part of the reason why I make such paraphrases!)

Comment: @Brian: I'm curious what triggers qualms from you. Maybe I'm suffering a lack of imagination, but cphq is about as questionable as one can get without coming outright and saying "I'm cheating" (or nearly so).

Comment: @Hurkyl: The abbreviation *cphq* is already prejudicing the issue: *cpq* would be considerably more accurate. (And even when the questions **are** homework, their appearance here is not necessarily cheating.) I have no trouble coming up with alternative explanations for such posts; a number of legitimate ones have been mentioned by me and others here and in similar threads in the past. Another is simple laziness, and you know, I don’t mind offering a hint to the lazy: it might actually prompt some thought.

Comment: @Brian: Okay... so? Are you back to saying that one should ignore questionable activity on the grounds that it is merely questionable?

Comment: Yes, there can be alternative explanations -- AFAIK nobody has *ever* contested that. That's why we have WHYT prompts: (at face value) they intend to prod the poster to show they are actually involved in their question. That's why closing *with an informative explanation* is proposed; to stem the tide of problematic posts while giving those acting in good faith a chance to improve their question.

Comment: @Hurkyl: If the alternative to ignoring it is treating everyone who posts a cpq as a potential cheat, then yes, I much prefer ignoring it. And I have a strong impression that a good many of the WHYT prompts are offered reflexively, not really at face value at all. Finally, I don’t consider those questions a serious problem. I’ve heard basically two arguments. (1) The poster might be cheating. You know what I think of that argument. (2) They get in some people’s way. I don’t consider it acceptable to penalize the lazy, clueless, or thoughtless merely for someone’s convenience.

Comment: @Brian: Actually, yes you do consider it acceptable. You didn't seem to have *any* problem whatsoever to penalize someone too lazy, clueless, or thoughtless to realize they should ask about the Wronski Feint over at scifi.stackexchange.com rather than on math.stackexchange.com. What reason could we possibly have for closing questions as off topic if not because they get in the way?

Comment: You've missed at least three more reasons, expressed in short: (3) They make for bad questions. (4) They set a bad example. (5) They are off topic. Although I suppose (2) is just a glib statement of (5).

Comment: @Hurkyl: I don’t buy the argument that they’re off-topic, and I don’t accept that (3) and (4) are sufficient justification for the widespread guilty-until-proven-innocent attitude.

Comment: I see on another thread that we have had a series of questions from a take-home exam posted here recently. If more of us adhered to a policy of voting to close no-effort (unmotivated, unsourced) questions on sight, these questions might have been closed before any damage could be done.

Comment: @Brian It is exactly because we are not mind reader that we want the OP, the person who has the best access to hir own mind, to provide enough information. I think outright lying is a minor problem in this case.

Comment: @Brian: Who's pushing for guilty-until-proven-innocent? If we stick to justice system analogies, the proposal under consideration is far more analogous to a cop compelling a person loitering suspiciously to either move along or provide a reasonable explanation than a judge rendering a jail sentence.

Comment: @Brian: But unlike the justice system side of the analogy, nobody will suffer an existence failure if *we* make a type I error. Invoking the analogy ***greatly*** distorts what the appropriate balance between type I and type II errors should be; there simply isn't any reason for such *extreme* measures to avoid false positives.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You are pushing for guilty-until-proven innocent. And that cop is behaving improperly unless *suspiciously* is **very** narrowly defined $-$ in which case your analogy fails. // Existence failures are rarely the outcome of such errors in the justice system, either. I completely disagree with the rest of your comment. There is no problem here that warrants violating a fundamental principle.

Comment: @Gerry: So you want to penalize a bunch of people who are at worst lazy or clueless in order to catch an occasional serious cheat? No, thanks! They’re separate problems, if the former really is a problem rather than a minor nuisance.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I can’t make head or tail of your *yes you do consider it acceptable* comment; the part that isn’t incoherent seems to indicate that you utterly misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: @Michael: I also want the OP to provide enough information. I frequently ask for more in the comments. But I have no problem living with OPs who are less than helpful. If I think that I can still provide a potentially useful answer, and I feel like doing so, I will; if not, I’ll simply move on. I might check back later to see whether matters have improved, or I might not, but either way, **that question isn’t hurting me**.

Comment: @Brian, I don't want to penalize anybody --- I just want to give people an incentive for improving their questions. Closing exam questions before they get answered is just a side-benefit.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott They aren't hurting me either, but my concern is that *if* some students are copying assignment questions verbatim (assessed or not) and getting full answers they can hand in without even having to understand the question, then it is hurting these students. I don't think the fact that it's mostly their own fault (there are a couple of external factors that seem to encourage this kind of behaviour) should mean we ignore the problem, and reaffirm this behaviour by providing answers.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't be happy to have an official policy preventing people from answering such questions unless there was community consensus supporting such a policy, which it seems there isn't.

Comment: People who post questions have already decided, based on much more information than we have, that an answer would be beneficial to them.  The idea that answers are "hurting" the OPs seems to assume that we are omniscient enough to overrule that judgement, and its logical conclusion is to never give any help on any homework question no matter how much effort the OP displays.  Maybe no question should ever receive an answer; saving time to the OP prevents a valuable opportunity to learn through hard work.  @MattPressland

Comment: @Hurkyl, I don't think that it is helping the cause to slime a genial retired math professor, using a long stream of patronizing comments to try and convince everyone that his morals are slippery or that he represents a type of internet criminal eroding the ethical foundations of the world as we know it.  The simpler thing would be to stick to the subject and not assume personal control over the interpretation of terms like *questionable*, *ethical*, *cheating*, etc.  What is unethical, exactly, about (knowingly) answering homework?

Comment: @Matt: I understand your view, but I decided long ago that by the time they reach college, students should be allowed to make that decision for themselves. That doesn’t mean that I condoned cheating when I caught it, but I did refuse to go out of my way to prevent it, and I didn’t worry about the fact that some undoubtedly escaped my notice, or the occasional cheating that I suspected but couldn’t prove. (Frankly, I suspect that most cheating that escaped my notice altogether did result in some learning: they had to understand enough to put it into their own words.)

Comment: My experience has been that students use their homework solutions when studying for exams. Much, much better in that case that it be done from a correct and complete solution copied from the internet, than some fuzzy thing that they created on their own. (@BrianM.Scott )

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What would you like rep on MSE to stand for? True mathematical talent? This already exists: it is called publishing in the few journals with very high standards. Or, better, solving a longstanding problem. I think that nobody will deny that one gets many more upvotes by answering a trivial question in two seconds (I know that's how I got most of my rep), than by spending some time on a more delicate one. I don't find it that annoying. I just don't pay much attention to rep.

Comment: @julien: If you can completely ignore the rep game, I'm happy for you. Often I can, but not always. I absolutely enjoy the site more on the days, when I can ignore it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I simply hope the rep thing does not bother you too much on the days you don't ignore it. Regards.

Comment: @Jyrki: I had a lot more fun with [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/354130/12042) than with [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/216350/12042)!

Comment: @Hurkyl, to avoid redundancy in the "JDH" discussion I point you to the comments under Qiaochu answer, where I think your point is answered.  JDH did, in fact, say something about posts in the imperative and their presumed solution-copying student authors : that complete, ready to copy, answers to those questions are beneficial to the students.  He did not give ethics lectures, and maybe it was lucky for him to not have posters in meta at the time inclined to paint his proposals as thoughtcrime.

Comment: I love how whenever someone disagrees, the other side often tries to equate their disagreement with totalitarianism, judicial process, extreme violence, and death. It really paints the discussions on meta with some deep colors.

Comment: In the old thread, Brian Scott took a less extreme position than JDH, and if you read a few comments up here you will notice Prof. Scott being explicitly painted as a thinker of Bad Thoughts.  So the comment was fairly exact.  Another characteristic of thought policing is that it is never necessary to answer questions (such as the ones put to Hurkyl many times) about the party line. Asaf is mocking what is a highly realistic description of goings on in the meta.

Comment: @zyx: Where, exactly, do you think JDH is advocating writing answers for cphq? I've read through some of the comments in the rest of that thread, and the only other thing I've noticed him discussing is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21630/proof-by-double-induction-on-strings-solved) which is practically the *polar opposite* of the topic of this discussion, especially in the question's initial revision.

Comment: What question, exactly, do you think I'm not answering? Scrolling back, the last question you directed at me is `What is unethical, exactly, about (knowingly) answering homework?` Why would I bother answering that? Not only does it have nothing to do with what I'm saying, the tone of your comment suggests it was rhetorical anyways. You are confusing homework in general with the special case of cphq.  (Or deliberately disregarding it, I suppose....)

Comment: And despite his repetition of it, I honestly don't believe Brian Scott honestly believes that questionable activity should not be questioned; instead, I think he simply disagrees on what constitutes questionability. But even assuming that's correct, there can't be any progress in the discussion until that is *actually admitted*. So I'm left with reducing the arguments that are *actually made* to absurdity until such time that he is willing to admit that the question of whether to take action against cphq isn't about lofty principles, but a mundane evaluation of what merits action.

Comment: @Hurkyl: It is indeed a matter of principle. The principle is that it is not acceptable to take any action that effectively presumes guilt that has not been proved. If you wish to say that this is simply a ‘mundane evaluation’ that only proven guilt ‘merits action’, feel free, but it’s a distinction without a difference. // Your first sentence is a real gem: it seriously misrepresents what I’ve said in this discussion (unless your understanding of *questioning* is *accusing of cheating more or less in so many words*) and calls me a liar to boot $-$ without even pinging me. I’m trying hard ...

Comment: ... to stay out of the mud, but you’re making it increasingly difficult.

Comment: @Brian: I don't think you're a liar; I think you're one of the many people who repeatedly argue `Q` because they know `P -> Q` and either don't notice, can't imagine, or refuse to consider that `P` could be a topic of discussion.

Comment: @Brian: Let's take another tack. You appear to be denying the existence of a middle area between "assume there is no cheating" and "assume there is cheating". If so, why? If not, then why do you speak only in terms of these polar opposites?

Comment: @Hurkyl: When you ask a question that isn’t based on a distortion of what I’ve actually said here, I’ll try to answer it. (I do not believe, by the way, that the distortion is deliberate, but I’ve had enough.)

Comment: @Brian: Then... you are disagreeing with my perception that you are speaking only in terms of the polar opposites? If you've said anything about the middle ground in-between all of the "presumption of guilt" jabs, then I've missed it. This is pretty unfortunate, since my discussion with you the past couple days has been primarily designed to establish the existence of the middle ground before I move onto further arguments that depend on its existence.

Comment: Specifically, that identifying something as not being "assume innocent" is not sufficient justification for inferring that it is "assume guilty". To help fix what I mean by these phrases, I consider locking the door to your house to be in the middle ground, and I also consider a trial by jury to be in the middle ground.

Comment: @Brian: I suppose it doesn't matter. We have 5 answers that say "we need to close more often" totaling 88 upvotes and 11 downvotes, four of which write varying degrees of support for that position. We have 2 answers that say effectively say "cphq is a problem that needs to be addressed, but I don't think closing is the right solution" totaling 8 upvotes and 2 downvotes containing explicit rationale for their judgment that can be discussed and addressed. And we have zero answers from people who wish to defend cphq's presence on the site.

Comment: ... I think we're ***long*** past the point where the people who want to defend the presence of cphq on the site really need to actually put forth positive arguments defending their position rather than effectively just repeating "I'm not convinced".

Comment: @Hurkyl: Positive arguments have been given in the comments. I don’t know whether you’ve failed to recognize them as such, failed to understand them, or simply chosen to pretend that they weren’t made, but I’ve no reason to think that gathering them into an answer would be anything but a waste of yet more of my time. You’re on a crusade. *shrug*

Comment: @Brian: In exchanges with you, I've defending a proposed policy, a point of view, and *myself* from being painted with the brush of "it presumes guilt" from someone who makes no reasonable attempt to actually justify the label -- and ironically has both claimed to be staying "out of the mud" and who has decried the art of "mind reading" to make inferences about the motivations of posts.

Comment: If it pleases you to call that a crusade, then *shrug*. I will admit to being excited about the prospect of the possibility that policy on MSE might take a small step towards being more reasonable, rather than the prior (perceived) climate of the community being paralyzed by indecision. (which, of course, has the effect of making the "no moderation" position the de-facto policy)

Comment: @MathGems [*On the other end of the spectrum are users who strive to write answers that are "proofs from the book", and to collect and organize such beautiful proofs on this site.*]
I think there are many users who strive to write answers which are not found in any existing textbooks.

Comment: If someone could please explain, why is anyone at all required to attempt to solve a problem before posting? This doesn't seem write at all. I never see anywhere that says this is a "try first, then ask, and maybe get answered" site. This is a Q & A site. If someone doesn't know AT ALL how to proceed with a question, then you're basically telling them to go jump in a creek. Now I will admit that word problems are a little weird to ask on here. However, I don't see why we should immediately ban or remove questions simply because we think they are homework. A cheating user will get caught in RL.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Have you read the comments about this? But a couple of things. (1) The Stackexchange model isn't like all other Q&Z sites. It is unique in that there are fairly strict criteria for what is on-topic. (2) Not all cheaters will be caught in real life. Try to find some statistics showing how many students actually cheat on exams. It is surprising and definitely not all are caught. Even if many are caught, some on this site don't want to be part in a students attempts at cheating.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: (cont.) (3) The point about providing context is also to help us all answer the questions. If the question is just a problem statement I have no idea what about the problem confuses you. Providing context can sometimes just mean that you explain where you came across the problem. Is the problem related to a class? What is your background? What tools are available to you? Answering these questions will help us provide better answers that target your specific area of need.

Comment: @(cont.) (4) Lastly I would say, if you are very unhappy about how things work around here, why not just go some place else? There are plenty of other sites where you can find help.

Comment: Sir, this a discussion. I should be allowed to voice my opinion in a constructive manner. No I did not read every single previous post. That would be far too many posts to digest. I understand that we don't want cheating on the site. I agree. On the other hand, how can it be right to close questions simply because we /think/ it looks like homework? Sure 20 questions in a row that were copy pasted from a book is suspicious, but I don't see what the fuss is? After all nobody has to answer a question.

Comment: Plus, most institutions I know of allow for tutoring help as long as you actually do the work yourself (though I personally disagree with such a policy) so it's not like we cannot give a more general and long lasting answer about methodology (which is the goal of the site anyways, IMO).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I was just trying to answer your questions.

Comment: I understand. :) You're first statements about telling me to leave came across a bit accusatory. Like, "If you have a disagreeing opinion, you must leave period.". Of course, those sorts of opinions are rarely true in this world except in troll infested places like Reddit or the mind of Donald Trump. XD I just thought it was appropriate for me to try and let you know it wasn't the most appropriate way to phrase as to some less thick skinned people, it might come across as offensive. Anyway, thanks for the input, and I hope you have a wonderful time on the site. :)

Answer (score 58):

My opinion is that we should be substantially more aggressive about closing questions than we currently are. In particular, I think we should be substantially more aggressive about lazy homework questions than we currently are. The community currently disagrees with me about this in aggregate, or at least as measured by the most vocal of people who have responded to my expressing this opinion in the past.

Comment: I think that this site has grown large enough as it is without the need to attract more transient effortless homework questions. I recall people foreseeing a possible overrun by homework, and it certainly does seem to be the case. I would hate this to be an overrun by copy-paste homework questions.

Comment: Completely agree.

Comment: Growth of the site and homework/WHYT are different issues.  Policies related to the second are not likely to make a dent in the first.  Some data can be had from data.SE.com, but from user experience alone, I don't think that growth in homework questions explains the higher traffic on the site.  I also think that the burden of proof is on those claiming that the site is drowning in transient effortless homework questions.  Maybe the homework volume and quality is similar to what has always been the case, but MSE is overwhelmed by the total amount of traffic.

Comment: Concerning community disagreement and whether it is really only from the most vocal minority, I wonder what is your opinion of the community response to JDH's answer (at link #2 in the question, favored by a 50:5 margin), or the removal of the homework tag from Stackoverflow, or the WHYT ban also at SO.  Is it possible that there is either a majority, or a large minority (like 30-40 percent, not 3-4 percent) who disagrees with you, and the endless meta conflicts are partly or mainly due to a *small vocal faction* of student/academic types (can you say, "conflict of interest"?) not letting go?

Comment: @zyx: No one is arguing to ban all homework questions from the site (well, certainly some people do, but everybody should realize by now that it's not going to happen). What Qiaochu, and me, say is that people who just post copy-paste questions from a book (with perhaps the generous addition of "how to solve?" or some variant of this sentence) are *less* welcome on this site than they were two years ago. And this is exactly because there is a lot more traffic with *good* questions that work was put into. This is exactly the kind of questions I'd be happier with.

Comment: @zyx: I also have to ask: have you ever taught a class? have you ever stood by the board with the vacant stare of 3-35 students mindlessly droning what you write and explain? Have you tried to stimulate them in any way? To help, with your own two hands, to see a person struggling to understand? Later to have some of them in your office asking questions and trying to get the answers, or sometimes even understand the mathematics behind it? I ask because often I feel that some people who argue in "complete favour of any question" haven't had a lot of experience in that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, my number of years of teaching experience and non-academic (or "adult life") experience probably are several times (or for some aspects, close to an order of magnitude) larger than yours.  What I wonder, since you ask, is how much of the second category you and Qiaochu have.

Comment: @zyx: It's likely. Admittedly I don't have so many years behind me. This is my third year of teaching, but I taught (except this semester) only freshmen. But I can tell you that I put into my teaching roughly the same amount of energy I put into this site, which is a lot. And in those five semesters of vacant-eyed freshmen staring at me fumbling by the board I have learned a lot about teaching and explaining.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I have no doubt the vacant freshmen are fortunate to have you as instructor, but don't be too hard on them for their vacant-ness or lack of interest in mathematics or whatever (you said something about the non-HUJI teaching being awful).  I always considered it a happy experience to face students, no matter what.  If you don't naturally like it (and you seem like a social enough person) -- consider the alternatives!

Comment: @zyx: It's the engineering students that I disliked teaching. On fall semesters (this one included) I taught intro to logic and set theory in BGU. That one is nice and I have a lot of fun, despite the vacant eyes staring at me (because there's always this one guy to talk to in these classes). But that's not the point of this comments thread. The point is that people who don't put any effort in formulating the question are not the people I would like to answer (most of the time).

Comment: The preferences about well formulated questions and homework are really a political argument for you (or Qiaochu, or whoever cares to) to make, i.e., that MSE should be less receptive to homework.  I was not commenting on that, but the more empirically testable ideas that MSE is overrun, or in danger of being overrun, by the transient effortless homework questions, and the idea that the community doesn't really disagree so much with Qiaochu's hard line, it is only a tiny vocal minority.  I think the actual situation for both claims may be the opposite. (@AsafKaragila )

Comment: @zyx: I don't think that MSE should be receptive of **all** questions. There are plenty of questions being deleted, either by users or automatically *because* the site is not receptive of all questions. I think that we have a huge amount of questions per day, and I prefer to spend more time helping those who *try* to help themselves. This is not a "political argument" (I really don't see how politics is involved), but rather a call for revisiting the norms about homework. It's been a year and more, since those threads in the main post were debated. In this year **a lot** has changed.

Comment: Qiaochu already expressed your general point in his answer, and I am not arguing one way or the other (here) about what MSE should receive or not.  I am only expressing skepticism about Qiaochu's view of community agreement, and the idea that MSE is over-run by homework or in danger of this.  You say a lot has changed, and this is true for volume, but it's not clear to me that proportion or quality of homework has changed in a big or negative direction. @Asaf

Comment: A few minutes ago I went through all 48 questions listed on the main page. 15% of those were 'no effort' questions, according to (IMO) a very conservative judgement of what counts as a 'no effort' question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, just do as I do: If it is obvious homework, with no real interest and no work shown, pass it over. Life is too short to waste it on such nonsense, and teaching those who don't want to be thaugt.

Comment: @vonbrand: Too late: by the time you've seen that there is no real interest and no work shown, you've *already* wasted your time. But you seem to be missing the point that there are more far-reaching concerns: e.g. the association of the site (and its contributors) with academic integrity (or lack thereof), or even more modest things like the proportion of questions there will be in the future that aren't a waste of time. If you don't want to spend time on a kind of question, then surely you should support others who want to spend time getting rid of them so that your time doesn't get wasted.

Comment: @Hurkyl, point taken.

Comment: I repeated the experiment and got between 4 and 7 (by strict or liberal standard) of 48.  The percentage a user would see when reading the site is lower as we use filters and heuristics to prioritize the selection, such as descriptive title and tags, correct use of mathematical words, etc.  It also becomes clear when doing the exercise of reading everything on the main page, that the ideas of demonstrated effort and "what have you tried" don't make any sense for many categories of question (numbers are similar to what @Hurkyl and I were counting).

Comment: Can we be sure the great majority of the comunity disagrees with Qiaochu's suggestion nowadays when his post is the highest-thumbed on this answer stream?

Comment: @mike4ty4, do you think that (a) meta voters who (b) are drawn to the title "closing questions that show no effort - official policy" are a totally random sample of the community?  Also, was the assertion that a *great majority disagrees*, or that a significantly large subset does?  There was a 50 to 5 majority of votes on this answer (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1661/14120 ), with *one* new downvote due it being cited several times in the recent homework discussions.  I doubt that all those upvoters disappeared or changed their minds.

Comment: @zyx: People who stay off meta, stay off deciding and debating norms and policies. Much like I avoid voting and politics in real life, and I have no say in how the government wastes their money not granting me a tenured position (yes, I want to be the first tenured Ph.D. student).

Comment: @zyx: Who are the people you count as belonging to the "community"?   And how in the world is JDH's post relevant to this (which I upvoted, btw). Nobody, here argues that homework problems are inherently bad. JDH made lots of points, he certainly did not said nothing in defense of copy pasting questions and not showing any effort.

Comment: However "the community" is defined, it is fairly obvious that there is a large self-selection effect (among other biases) skewing the numbers one sees next to answers and comments.  @Hurkyl aptly stated that there is a "disgruntled" population with respect to homework postings, and this affects voting patterns and the relative frequency of different opinions being voiced on the meta, the strength of the impulse to follow threads and up/down votes, and other manifested signals.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, JDH "defended" posting complete answers to copy-paste homework. Look for the words "posts in the imperative" and discussion after that, just below his answer.  He did not say anything about what posting style should or should not be used for homework questions.

Comment: @zyx He wrote it is fine that there are lots of homework questions, "particularly interesting ones". He wrote that answers should be well written. He wrote that he encourages cooperation among students. The discussion afterwards is not what got the 50 upvotes. And that he did not write abut how HW questions should be adressed does not imply that the post supports all forms of writing HW questions. The post also did not adress human trafficking, I don't take this as a sign of approval for human trafficking.

Comment: @Michael JDH also wrote **"So my opinion is that there is no homework issue to speak of"** It is anybody's guess just which of his many points the current  $\,+50,\, -7\,$ votes target. Ditto for the $\,+29,\, -4\,$ votes on Qiaochu's answer above (e.g. the upvotes could represent agreement with his claim that "the community disagrees with me about this"). The votes on any meta answer that does not have an unambiguous *unique* targeted point are essentially meaningless.

Comment: @MathGems: The issue of CPHQ without any effort *didn't really exist in the collective mind of the community back then*. Let me quote Aristotle and tell you that the Earth is the center of the universe, and the sun revolves around it.

Comment: @Asaf I highly doubt that the *percentage* of no-effort-shown questions has changed much since the site started. Rather, it is the *volume* that has increased, as has the volume of any category of questions. The same concerns will need to be addressed when the volume of "good" questions becomes overwhelming to those complaining (whatever "good" means to them, which is becoming harder and harder to infer as this meandering thread evolves). This was not a problem in usenet newsgroups because many newsreaders had good filters. The same solution would work here.

Comment: @MathGem: One 1mg of coniine diluted in a 10cc water is not going to kill you. 200mg of coniine diluted in 2000cc water will kill you. Have you noticed how the percentage didn't change?

Comment: @Asaf Which did not apply e.g. to sci.math, and does not apply here. What good are false analogies?

Comment: @Math Gems: Are there people using sci.math nowadays? I mean, except WM and the remainder of the users that stayed there to argue with him, and with those like him?

Comment: @Asaf I meant sci.math in its heydey - which had far more volume than we do now (and probably a much higher percentage of no-effort-shown questions). The difference being that on sci.math one was *forced* to be proficient with filtering etc to weed out the cranks and other nonsense. But here such volume issues are only recently forcing users to realize that better filtering tools are needed. Whether it is with "homework" or other popular questions, these issues will need to be confronted sooner or later. Better to find a general solution now, perhaps lobbying SE for better tools if need be.

Comment: @Math Gems: Do tell me. Was there any real moderation on sci.math? Was it possible to close and/or delete posts? I am unfamiliar with USENET (when I came to the internet 16 years ago it was already in decline, and I could never get those servers to work anyway).

Comment: @asaf No, sci.math was not a moderated newsgroup. There was a moderated sci.math.research for "research level" posts, but it was very low traffic (moderated newsgroups generally were not popular). Posts could not be closed or edited, but the author could cancel a post. The [Usenet Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) is a good introduction.

Comment: @Math Gems: Well, there you have it. To a man with no electricity, a computer is useless. There were no tools to handle these issues on sci.math; but there are tools for that *here*. Therefore these things *do* bother us because we *can* do something about them. So any analogy to Usenet is flawed, because the set of tools available for the core community to deal with issues is very different between the two worlds.

Comment: No, there *were* tools, but they were in the newsreaders, some of which had very elaborate tools for filtering and scoring posts. Without such there would have been no hope to cope with large volume newsgroups like sci.math (which was always in the top-handful newsgroups in terms of volume of posts).

Comment: @MathGems It seems newsgroup were something used by the most techsavy people in mathematics. I'm not sure how easily that transfers to a broader group.

Comment: @Michael Some were, but most were not. Often new users started with newsreader profiles from friends, universities, companies, etc that  were a good first approximation for filtering out noise. The noise was much higher there, and many serious users coped with it by using appropriate filtering technology (including many prolific contributors here, e.g. M. Suarez-Alvarez, R. Chapman, B. Dubuque, G. Edgar, R. Israel, R. Johnson, A. Magidin, G. Myerson, A. Nicolas, B. Scott, etc)

Comment: @MathGems Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MathGems, in fact, I used next to no filtering technology on sci.math; I did my filtering by hand, as it were.

Comment: @Gerry That must have been much work. It probably would have saved you much time if you had used tools from a good newsreader, e.g. Emacs Gnus.

Comment: @MathGems, I used Newswatcher, which grouped posts by thread and displayed the author of each post. It was not hard to tell which posts and which entire threads to "mark as read", equivalent to deleting them without looking at the actual post.

Comment: @Michael: No, Usenet was used by all sorts of people, many of them **not** particularly knowledgeable about computers. ASCII is a bloody awful way to have to write mathematics, but I miss the good days of Usenet: I dislike almost all of the web-based discussion interfaces that I’ve seen. MSE is about the only exception to that, and that’s partly because its special-purpose.

Comment: @Gerry: I didn’t even bother to delete: I just skipped. But I agree: one look at the subject and the pattern of authors in the thread tree was usually enough, and if not, reading a couple of posts was.

Comment: Qiaochu, it seems that the next time this issues pops up your answer will compete with that of JDH on the consensus of the masses... :-)

Comment: @Asaf: looking at the early threads on homework, the meta posters have changed, with the balanced voices of reason active in earlier times mostly replaced by an anti-homework/cheating bloc (with far lower academic credentials).  JDH has not logged in since September, Matt E posts a comment once per month, and similar participation reductions for others.  So the drumbeat for more and more control becomes a one-sided domination of the meta.

Comment: @zyx: I don't know why JDH and Matt E have stopped using the site on a regular basis. In the case of JDH I can only guess it has something to do with meta drama which somewhat drove him off (the MO 2.0 migration thread). But given the situation, the remaining users have the absolute right to form their own consensus. If this consensus is that CPQ are bad, then so be it. If and when JDH returns he could voice his opinion on CP(H)Q, and then we can agree or disagree with him. But what you really have to stop saying is anti-HW/cheating bloc. **NO ONE IS AGAINST HOMEWORK** JUST AGAINST COPY-PASTE.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, the relevance of the +50 on JDH's post is that he not only totally dismissed the homework issue (as far as giving complete solutions was concerned), but also called it a *beneficial* thing to provide full solutions for lazy copy-the-solution OPs (see the first comments there).  This is rather different from the current climate of "ethics mania" in which it is claimed that great evil takes place, cheating is promoted, the pillars of morality collapse and so on. //// Asaf: I never confused HW and CPHQ, and there is very much a bloc on the cheat/CPHQ/exam/contest matters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what is this "new" situation?  Read Yuval (another lost participant) comment at the top of the JDH thread.  He says the homework tag can be deleted because every posting is homework.  An exaggeration, but interesting for Before and After comparison.  It's not likely the percentage of homework, or of CPHQ within the homework, was tiny then and suddenly exploded.

Comment: @zyx: This is not about percentage, it's about absolute quantities. As I wrote Math Gems, 1% coniine solution is still lethal if you drink 2000cc of it. We get *so many* new questions every day, and it seems that I am not the only regular who enters many of them. It gets annoying to see more and more copy-paste questions. This is not about homework as it is about putting effort into your question. You don't even have to tell us what you did, if you do tell us what you know and don't know. But **some** effort is nice. It makes a bad user experience, and broken windows theory etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you will need to explain more the part about absolute quantities, because logically it would seem that the fraction of your site reading time in which you see some type of posting is controlled by its percentage in the pool.

Comment: @zyx: If CPQ **always** made 10% of the questions posted every day, when the site was younger and we would have something like 50 questions a day that wasn't a huge deal. Only five questions were CPQ. But when you have 300 questions posted every day, 30 CPQ questions is a lot more. It's six times more. At least according to http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/89504/ there were over 10,000 questions asked during March, which averages out as roughly 350 questions every day. It's a lot of questions, and I want the resources of posting answers to go to those who put effort into theirs.

Comment: @zyx: And while I can't back this up in any numerical way, I doubt that the CPQ percentage was 10% of the overall questions during March, I would be inclined to believe it was closer to 20%. That means that just last month over 2,000 questions were copy-pasted into this site without any effort on the site of the OP to even write what they know or don't know. That's insane.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, your number of questions read per day is similar to before, no?  The day did not become twice as long.  This means percentage governs what you see.  And the number of people who answer has scaled, because questions are getting mopped off the unanswered list *very* fast compared to before.  So I don't see a resource issue yet, or why the total number matters for individual reading experience of the site.  What really has changed is much fewer people reading every question and voting.  Whatever you post now, relative few people will see or care compared to before.

Comment: @zyx: No. When there were 50 new questions every day, I would read them all. When there were 100, I would read 80, when there were 200, I would read 120, when there are 300 I would read 150. Of course that if it is a day I have little time to the computer I would read about 10-20, but that's hardly ever the case. I read *more* and more. If not read thoroughly, I *open* more and more questions and glance over them. I do that while reviewing, and I do that while looking over the main page in a rate of once every several minutes (unless composing a long answer).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, this indicates you have an unscalable personal reading method, but for most of us it is $N$ minutes per day with a limit independent of how much is on the site.   There is no way I can follow more than a tiny slice of what is here.  This dis-integrates the site and kills the "collective memory" of questions that exists at smaller velocity sites like MathOverflow or meta.MSE.   So we are turning into Stackoverlow.  It is what it is, but they got rid of the homework tag and banned what-have-you-tried comments.  Volume has everything to do with that. They do use close votes more.

Comment: @zyx: I have absolutely no idea where did the $O(N^2)$ come from. I also don't know whether or not the core users has scalable or unscalable reading methods, because when the site changed so much in the past year, I doubt no one adapted themselves to this change except me.

Comment: I deleted that part of the comment, but I meant that things where users police each other causes conflict, and the number of potential conflicts scales more like the number of *pairs* of people, so this is fatal for the high traffic sites and they need to cut the number of pairwise interactions.  What you have explained so far is that you read more and more questions as the site grew.  I doubt most people do that; they have a limit. And whatever the number they read per day, the fraction of the time that they see CPHQ is still determined by percentage.  So the issue was and is percentage.@Asaf

Comment: @zyx: I completely disagree with your statement. I don't think people still read $X$ questions a day. But first let's clarify what "read" means. It means a scanning read of the question and judging whether or not you want to read it in depth. It does not mean to sit and read it carefully. The latter is probably a constant, yes. But more people are exposed to *more* questions, what with the review tools, and the fact that there are more questions to be exposed to. And these two facts increase the change that the user is exposed to CPQ, because those are reviewed more often.

Comment: By *read* I mean whatever people do when using the main site.  Once the site grows large enough (we are past the point a long time ago) the number of questions is effectively infinite for a user's reading process and the total number does not matter, it is the proportions of things that will influence user experience.  New features like the reviews changes this only temporarily when it is introduced and people change their routine.  But afterward the same principle holds: absolute number changes nothing, proportions rule.  The ancient history you liked was the pre-infinite regime, sorry. @Asaf

Comment: @zyx: Okay, then tell me. Let's entertain the notion that 20% of new questions are CPQ. If I read exactly 50 questions a day, and there are 70 CPQ posted every day; is it possible that I read 10 of them? If there are 1000 CPQ posts every day and I still only read 50. What are the odds now?

Comment: The same (expected number; variance very slightly higher, but essentially the same).  CPQ are placed randomly in the stream.  @AsafKaragila

Comment: @zyx: Then why do people keep complaining that they see more CPQ posts than before? Explain that, if you would. And "lying for political reasons because they belong to the "burn all the HW questions" bloc" is not a correct answer. Assume, for a moment, that people say that without an agenda -- but because they really do feel that way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, it is hard for me to say, because *I* do not experience that, and I am not using any automatic filters, but at the same time, I am not as concerned about CPQ so not constantly monitoring it compared to the previous recent months.  Data would be nice.

Comment: @zyx: Yes, data would be nice. But it would also require to be picked by hand, because we can't really filter CPQ automatically. So because you feel it, you can easily dismiss all those other people on this page that have complained to this problem? Similarly, I don't see any problems in finance right now. I don't know what all those people cry about all over the world. And I'm not particularly rich or anything...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, try to stop with the rhetoric (especially the non-stop extraneous analogies) or this is a waste of time.  You seem to agree, finally, that percentage is the relevant thing.  I don't say that CPQ did or not change percentage.  All I know is that because I have not seen *drastic* change, the trends are more likely to be subtle than overwhelming.   We are being told by people who want more control measures that there is a state of emergency and it is reasonable to ask how they know that.  I did not dismiss your experiences despite the nonscaling methods used, so why dismiss mine?

Comment: @zyx: This **is** a huge waste of time. Because you insist that the universe is perfectly in sync with probability and statistics, but I point out evidence that it is not (no, not data -- I point out that there are in fact users complaining that your modeling is incorrect). **YOU** may have not seen a drastic change, but some people feel that there has been a change, and that it is drastic enough to make them try and formulate a new social norm. I don't see why you keep insisting that just because you don't see a problem, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, could you tell us, after re-reading the last comment (and as many earlier ones as you need), where I have insisted that no problem exists because I don't see one in my user experience?  Or where I *keep insisting* on this position that, in fact, I never took and, uh, just stated the exact opposite ("I don't say CPQ did or did not change percentage")?  The nicest interpretation is that you comment without really reading and it would be great if for once the methodology would change.

Comment: Not that I pushed any probability models, either.  You stated a hard to believe and never clearly formulated model ("This is not about percentage, it's about absolute quantities"), I asked what you were talking about, and there was no coherent answer.  As far as I can understand, what you meant, concretely, is that *the site got much bigger* (true!) but this is not directly related to the CPHQ prevalence.  As a hint, Hurkyl calculated percentage of CPHQ on the front page.  MathGems told you percentage was the relevant thing.  I don't think they were telling the universe how to behave. @Asaf

Comment: @zyx: Ohhh!!! Math Gems told me so?? Why didn't you say that earlier... I completely forgot that this person whose name I don't even know is my one true god and every single word he utters onto this website is my command. Get real, would you? No, this is not about percentage, it's about absolute quantities. You don't need 100% of your body to shut down before you die, you just need a particular organ to do so. The site got much bigger, so there are more CPQ's posted every day. Whether or not the percentage is similar (and I reckon it's not, due to broken windows theory), is irrelevant. [cont]

Comment: [...] What's important is the fact that more than a handful core users **do notice** that there is a problem. **You** did not notice that problem. Good for you! Golden star award, huzzah. $\color{yellow}\star$. My point to begin about percentage and site growth was not that there is a probability of $X$ that you run into CPQ, but that nominally there are a lot more, and *you do* run into them more often. And much like how HW consists of the majority of this website, with time CPQ might take the same. I don't have a problem with HW, I have a problem with posts without any effort put into them.

Comment: I'll try this one last time and hope that you won't comment only for the sake of commenting.  Nothing the other users say (let's assume they are right, it is bad and getting worse) contradicts "percentages" as the way to think about this.  It would just say the percentage is getting higher.  The problem with this "absolute numbers" theory is that nobody, not even you, seems to understand what you are talking about when you say it, or why the total is important.  The absolute number of non-homework questions has grown even more than the homework questions, but are we are drowning in them? @Asaf

Comment: No one, **ever** understood what they were talking about. If people would know what they talk about the world wouldn't be in this mess. With your experience in life, which dwarfs mine like a planet dwarfs a quark, I would have expected you to know that by now. @zyx

Comment: I guess we're done if it's down to pure sarcasm (or something).  Be well. @Asaf

Comment: @Asaf: The word *notice* in the statement that some core users do notice that there is a problem implies that there is a problem that exists independent of the preferences, mindset, manner of using MSE, etc. of the observer. But it’s not a matter of noticing or failing to notice something: some core users are experiencing a problem, and some are not. There is no objectively present problem that you are noticing and I am not; rather, the growth of the site has created a problem for you that does not exist for me.

Comment: It is *objectively* clear that a number of contributors find the current state of affairs problematic. And if nothing else, *that* is a problem.

Comment: I am of the opinion that the prevalence (perceived or real) of cphq doesn't really change what the correct policy should be -- it merely changes how imperative it is to deal with the issue.

Comment: @Brian: If I'm not the only one to sense a problem exists, then I usually assume that a problem *does* exist, and perhaps some people prefer to ignore it (much like I ignore other problems). The fact that I am not the only one to perceive a problem related to this issue means that there is in fact a problem, at least in the conscience of *some* core users. Whether or not this is enough to constitute as "exists" I can't tell, but for me it does, and it is. There is a problem, and it seems that I am not the only one who feels that way. I also feel that we all want the same thing [cont.]

Comment: However we prefer different approaches to that thing. This is very much like whether or not synthetic products are good or bad for you; these are clearly unnatural but you can't argue with the fact that lifespan has become longer. Similarly there are two factions "This is unnatural" and "Lifespan is longer!". It doesn't really matter which side is which, but the point is that we don't know whether or not CPQ are going to spell the inevitable doom of the site or not. Some people think it might, and prefer to stop it; others think it won't harm anything, and prefer to just ignore it [cont, last]

Comment: "*The future is all around us, waiting in moments of transition, to be born in moments of revelation. No one knows the shape of that future, or where it will take us. We know only that it is always born in pain.*" - Book of G'Quan.

Comment: @Asaf: My impression from the discussion is that some want to be morals police, some haven’t yet found a way to cope with the growth of the site, a few are mostly concerned about providing the greatest benefit to those asking questions, and a few may just have the mentality of a petty bureaucrat. I’m sympathetic to the two middle groups, but I don’t think that closing questions left and right is an acceptable remedy for the first group, and my experience is the kind of interaction desired by the second group already takes place quite often even with questions that initially show no effort.

Comment: How do you know that a question is homework if it's not tagged as homework?

Comment: @AsafKaragila [*I think that this site has grown large enough as it is without the need to attract more transient effortless homework questions. I recall people foreseeing a possible overrun by homework, and it certainly does seem to be the case. I would hate this to be an overrun by copy-paste homework questions.*] How do you know a question is homework without the tag?

Comment: @Makoto: I have zero intentions to have any discussion which is not mathematical with you (since you have made it very clear to me in the past, you are not looking for discussions), and even in the mathematical case I'm thinking three times before engaging you. This let alone for a discussion from over a year ago. Instead, how about showing *any* interest in the answer that I have given you a month ago about the product of compact spaces? (You don't need to answer here, I'm not going to reply *here*. You're welcome to comment on that answer if you are interested in that.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila [*Instead, how about showing any interest in the answer that I have given you a month ago about the product of compact spaces?*]
Do you remember that I have been suspended since about a month ago?
Right now I have no intention in engaging in the main until [a meta issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13750/public-question-to-the-moderators) which is relevant to this thread is settled because I don't want to be suspended again.

Answer (score 35):

I am so frustrated with no effort, copy-paste homework questions that I would support a one-flag close/delete policy on them.  In my opinion, these are not on topic for MSE, and if they are, they **damn well shouldn't be.**

It's important to keep in mind **how many** of these questions we're getting.  In the past month I've found myself posting fewer and fewer answers because it's so difficult to find non-terrible questions.

I see a lot of comments here discussing precedents being set, slippery slopes, etc. but frankly that's a load of crap.  This line isn't blurry.  It's very clear when someone just wants us to do their homework for them.  We shouldn't sit around pretending there's nothing we can do about this problem.

I for one will vote to close; those who disagree can vote against.  That's why we have voting.

Comment: My enjoyment is also going downhill for a similar reason that the more interesting questions are fewer and fewer. However, that is also partly because the overall volume has gone up. Within the tags that I follow, there aren't too many CPHQs. If I could filter ignored tags away (as opposed to having one half of the front page white out), the site would be more enjoyable. About the CPHQers? It is pointless to blame anyone much. The askers, the answerers and the upvoters of those answers are all enablers of this. Trying to hunt them down and starting downvoting will just make me angry and...

Comment: (cont'd) waste my time. The answerers? I will just quitely ridicule them in the privacy behind my screen: "So the site has determined that you are an expert on HOMEWORK and PRECALCULUS. Congratulations, are you planning on graduating some time?"

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen To completely hide ignored tags, go to your profile, click prefs and check "hide ignored tags."

Comment: Thanks, @Ayman. How did I miss that?

Comment: @Jyrki: You didn't follow meta threads closely enough. This was discussed not too long ago. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8556/feature-request-hide-specific-questions#comment28783_8556

Comment: I have neither understanding of nor sympathy for your frustration. I find it incomprehensible. And it is flatly untrue that ‘It’s very clear when someone just wants us to do their homework for them’, if $-$ as seems to be the case $-$ you’re talking about copy-paste questions with no further comment. (And as I’ve said before, calling them CPHomeworkQ is prejudging the issue.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think it's obvious when a student is, essentially, trying to cheat using the site, rather than trying to get help understanding something.  There's a difference between copying someone's solution and getting tutored - I feel the latter belongs here and the former does not.  [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351754/12952) is how I feel homework questions should be phrased.  I don't see how you can find that "incomprehensible" - perhaps you disagree, but surely you must understand what I mean.

Comment: And yes, admittedly there are *occasionally* "grey area" cases with respect to the whole cheating vs. tutoring thing, but the vast majority of the time I think it's quite clear.  If the asker really is a motivated student, it shouldn't be hard for him to take 10 seconds to improve the quality of his question.   I think that's fair to ask considering we volunteer our time to write quality answers.

Comment: @Alexander: And I don’t think that it’s obvious. I think that you are falsely claiming to be able to read posters’ minds. How do you know that an unresponsive poster is just copying a solution and not learning from it? How do you know that the homework is even being turned in for a grade? In lower-level courses I assigned a great deal of homework for practice, to be discussed in class if there were questions, and none that was for a grade. Moreover, when I’ve given hints to these posters, a significant number of them have responded appropriately to the hint; you’d deny them the chance.

Comment: @Alexander: Fair? Why? If you don’t like the question, ignore it! I also volunteer my time, and I may want to answer that question. Or I may not. But I don’t want you deciding for me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't want either of us to be alienated, which is why I support an *official* change in homework policy, i.e. on the FAQ.  Those cooperative students would benefit much more if they mentioned what specifically they needed clarified.  It is *always* more helpful to be tutored interactively than to read a full solution, whether it's for a grade or not.  An improved homework policy would benefit everyone with an honest interest in learning.

Comment: @Alexander: If we get an official change, I will seriously consider leaving. // Of course interactive tutoring is better. And as I pointed out, I’ve had it happen more than a few times when your policy would have closed the question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So you'll leave if a compromise is made?  Go ahead then.  I appreciate your answers but this is a place for open discussion, not ultimatums.

Comment: @Alexander: (1) As I read your previous comment, you weren’t talking about a compromise: you were talking about a policy that would be at least very close to the one that you want. (2) I did not say that I would leave, and I might not do so; I said that I would seriously consider it. Your characterization of my comment as an ultimatum is as offensive as it is inaccurate. My comment was in fact intended to point out that I’m already more than a bit alienated, and that a policy strongly skewed in the direction that you favor is hardly likely to change that!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8236/discussion-between-alexander-gruber-and-brian-m-scott)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, while no expert, I *am* planning on graduating sometime! :)

Comment: For the record, Alexander and I had a very pleasant discussion in chat.

Comment: The Chaz, all. Sorry about that slur (somewhat surprised by 9 support votes and no  flags). Feeling much better now. Out of my meds for a couple of days due to a nasty (but short-lived) noro-virus.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I find this heated discussion heartwarming in a way. It is a sign that we all truly care about this community we have.

Comment: Your recent edit (fix a spelling) brought this answer to my notice. Around 18 (and sometimes all 20) of my close queue goes as no context questions. Even after years of effort the problem does not seem to wane. But we have to keep our efforts on in order not to lose sanity.

Answer (score 18):

I usually stay away from meta matters, but this is an issue I feel strongly enough about to want to contribute something to the discussion on. To make this actually an answer to the original question, you should see it as an attempt to explain why, if it were solely up to me, I would have a policy requiring that users posting "homework" questions (broadly interpreted) should indicate that they have spent some reasonable amount of time (generously interpreted) thinking about the problem before posting. (As I have stated in the comments, I'm not actually in favour of such a policy without more community support than there seems to be).

My experience of the education system in the UK is that during primary and secondary education (everything pre-university), a huge number of students are taught, ususally a little indirectly, that the most important thing when given a mathematical problem is to be able to get the answer correct. Actually understanding what the question is asking, or what the answer means, is not important at all, and nor is the ability to solve problems in a creative way. This attitude seems to be promoted in two main ways. The first is that students are constantly made to sit exams, and the schools rise and fall based on the exam results. The second is that the exam questions very rarely require any deep understanding or creative solutions - the actual content of the syllabus varies a little between exam boards, but the general theme is that even at A-Level (I think high school level is the US analogue), no proofs are required, and most of the syllabus consists of differentiating and integrating various expressions - the result being that the act of answering a question and the act of thinking about and understanding a question are more removed from each other than they generally would be, and the latter isn't much of a prerequisite for the former.

When these students go to university to do mathematics degrees, they regularly don't recognize the subject compared to what they did at school, and reactions to this are often either very positive or very negative. Those who react negatively tend not to like questions asking them to prove things, and prefer situations where all the questions they are asked have the same basic structure, and they can perform an algorithm to solve them (such students tend to be good at a lot of first year linear algebra - computing row echelon forms, sifting spanning sets, computing determinants and inverses and so on). However, what all the students (at least at the universities I've taught at) have in common is that they got very high marks in school, and are often extremely embarassed to find that they're now getting things wrong, or not understanding what they're being taught.

This reaction can be so extreme that ocasionally students will try to get a correct answer to a problem in whatever way they can - at the university I currently teach at, the problem sheets don't change too much from year to year, and one or two students usually manage to obtain the previous year's solutions, and even though the problem sheets *do not count for credit*, will write these model solutions down and hand them in to be marked. This demonstrates a complete misunderstanding of the fact that the problem sheets only exist for them to practice problem solving and to get feedback on their work - the model solutions are always provided anyway after the deadline, so they still get a "perfect" solution at the end of the process.

Students will also sometimes ask TAs (such as me) to just tell them the answers to problems - when a student does this I will *always* ensure that they've spent time thinking about the problem before I tell them anything. Often they haven't, to the point that they haven't even looked up the appropriate definitions. Once they've done that, I usually proceed with hints. The reason is that, as I've said in the comments, my attitude is that the process of thinking about the problem is more useful than getting the answer (and they'll get the answer later anyway). Being able to solve problems creatively is both significantly more useful in university level exams than school level exams (and students don't realise this at first), and I would guess is usually much more useful in "real life" after they finish their degree. I certainly find the problem solving skills I learnt on my degree programme significantly more useful than the actual information, and I do mathematical research for a living... Asking (politely) what somebody has tried is also a good way of starting a useful discussion on the problem.

These students will also ask questions online, and I try to respond in the same way (although the process of giving hints is a little more difficult on a platform like this). This is the reason for my WHYT comments. They aren't meant to be snarky, or accusations of cheating, as some users have suggested (although I take responsibility for the fact that the tone and motivation was appparently unclear), but are intended to be genuinely helpful in encouraging questioners to think before asking - while it may seem obvious to some of us, I genuinely believe that some questioners have not yet internalized that this will be helpful, and instead are satisfied with receiving a correct answer whether they understand it or not. I also believe that anybody providing full answers to such questions, as good-intentioned as they might be, is actually harming the education of the asker. I also think this is true independent of whether they got the question from a problem sheet given to them on a course, or if it was from a resource they are using for self-study.

To clarify my views on this slightly, I should also make plain a few things that I *don't* think. The primary one is that I don't think every user that copy-pastes a question from a textbook or an assignment does so without thinking about it. However my feeling is that the cost to such users of having to provide some indication of this is outweighed by the benefit to those who haven't thought before asking of being encouraged to do so. This is particularly true as this extra information is often helpful to answerers in ways that have been regularly pointed out by other commentators (neither of my two questions are "homework", and I tried to give an indication of my thoughts on both problems). I imagine that this could really be the main point of conflict here, that some users feel that requiring this additional effort on the part of askers is intrusive and outweighs any benefits. I can't really give an objective justification as to how the pros and cons on this point stack up - nor even imagine what such a thing would look like - so I can understand this just being a difference in priorities between different users.

Brian's point about askers for whom English is not a first language is a very good one, but I would hope that my requirement to indicate some effort is sufficiently minimal that they could get by without having to explain in detail what they did. If nothing else, an indication that English is not their first language could maybe be taken in lieu of an indication of prior thought, and would encourage answerers to write in simple English. Either way, I accept that this particular issue is a tricky one that my suggestion does not address very well.

The other thing I don't think is that users who copy-paste homework problems without thinking about them are necessarily cheating, or committing any kind of sin by doing so. As I said at the beginning, at least in the UK there are certain features of the education system that actively encourage this kind of behaviour, and I think many students who are harming their own education by doing this don't realise it - some polite encouragement to think before asking can be useful in this case I think. This is also why I described the assignment system at my own university, to emphasize that I still think this behaviour is harmful even when cheating is technically impossible because no credit is awarded.

Sorry this turned out to be so long - I hope at least it clarifies where I'm coming from on this issue and adds something to the debate.

Comment: It isn't the length, but the content; nice one, this answer. I liked it. I can only hope people who ask questions could always put as much thought-effort as you did in just writing this...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write on the other aspects of the issue. There is a wide variety of benefits to having a more restrictive policy in place, but it's easy for the totality of the issue to be overlooked when discussion gets bogged down over individual points of contention.

Comment: I agree. Nice input to the whole discussion.

Comment: I have been active on another site that did have a more restrictive policy; both that askers should show their efforts on a problem (and should have the expectation of working along with those helpers), and that answerers should write answers that explain or suggest, rather than writing posts that look like they are submitting their homework to their teacher.  And there it has been effective, and has gotten much positive feedback (both from students and their teachers)...

Comment: ... I had not seen any indication that students thought it an undue burden (aside from the *implication* of such when a student goes through a dozen iterations of posting a question and not doing anything more on the problem before finally getting banned), nor have answerers seemed troubled when they were reminded of policy (in fact, they agreed, and were a little embarrassed at giving into the temptation of showing off). So I was (and still am) quite mystified by the reactions here that act like the world would end if even the slightest restrictions were in place.

Comment: Yes. Especially to that part where it seem to outweigh the extra-work from those who did think about it. And I don't think that closing questions is that big of a deal. Especially if this is accompanied by polite comments. We are way beyond the point where reopening a question is difficult.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Here as everywhere I am opposed on principle to any rule, regulation, restriction, or policy for which there isn’t a **very** good reason, and I don’t consider any of the reasons advanced for this one nearly adequate to justify it. Under-regulation is almost always preferable to over-regulation. // I can draw no conclusion from your experience on the other site: it’s not clear that the site was sufficiently similar in scope, purpose, and demographics to be very relevant.

Comment: @Asaf: The proposed restrictions and the extra work put in by some querents aren’t comparable entities in the first place, so I don’t know how one can outweigh the other. Imposing restrictions has no effect on those who would already meet those restrictions. In any case, those who put in extra work on their questions already have their payoff: they’re likely to get better (or at least more useful) answers, and with less unpleasantness. And those who don’t have made their choice, consciously or otherwise.

Comment: @Brian: I think that it's a good way to educate people. To retort all the judicial metaphors, we are not executing them. We merely give them a minor fine (which is fully refundable once they correct their ways), and if a user hasn't learned after three times then it's likely they will never learn and that they are not that interested in learning. I don't know if I want such users using the site. I have seen enough places being ran over by people who insisted not to learn. If this is a teaching site, it should commit to this teaching, rather than prance around it.

Comment: I was thinking of writing up my thoughts on this matter, but this answer is very close to my own thoughts and very well put, so thanks.

Comment: How do you know that a question is homework if it's not tagged as homework?

Comment: @MakotoKato I haven't said anything that requires me to know that (see the end of paragraph 6).

Comment: @MattPressland [*I haven't said anything that requires me to know that (see the end of paragraph 6).*]
You wrote at the end of paragraph 6:
[*I also think this is true independent of whether they got the question from a problem sheet given to them on a course, or if it was from a resource they are using for self-study.*]
How do you know a question is from a problem sheet or a resorce that they are using from self-study?
In other words, how do you know it's not his original question?

Comment: @MakotoKato I don't - I'm guessing. I expect that I will be correct most of the time, but (crucially) I also don't believe it is actually a problem if I get it wrong. If the OP has come up with the problem themselves, then they probably have some context, and providing it is useful to people answering.

Comment: @MattPressland [*and providing it is useful to people answering.*]
The context is often personal. I don't think knowing it is useful for, nor relevant to, the solution.
My point is that a mathematical question should not be stated as a personal matter.

Comment: @MakotoKato OK, then we disagree, which isn't really a problem. If I'm helping someone with a problem, I like to know what they've already thought so that I know how to pitch the explanation, avoid duplicating things they've already done, etc. The context is not usually relevant to the mathematical content of the solution, but it does have a large effect on how I phrase an answer, and therefore (probably) on how useful that answer is to the OP.

Comment: @MattPressland You are demanding that we treat mathematical questions as personal ones.
This is problematic for the site.
Let us take for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232526/is-g-pg-is-a-p-group).
You ask him which part of the *particular* proof he doesn't understand.
Suppose you tell him how he can complete his proof along his line and he accepts your answer.
The case is closed and we miss all the different(and possibly better) proofs each of which has its own merit.

Comment: @MakotoKato I'm not *demanding* anything - I'm describing how I use the site, why I use that way, and why I would like to be able to continue to do so. I think the cons of allowing context-free questions outweight the pros, so I like to be able to vote to close them - but I'm not saying *everybody* should do that, or that I should be able to close questions without input from other users, or that other people shouldn't be able to vote to reopen them. Accepting an answer doesn't prevent further answers, so I don't understand your example.

Comment: It is true that my responses focus primarily on the person actually asking the question, and on people reading later only secondarily, but I also usually find that the answer I think is most useful for the OP is also the answer I think is most useful for people reading later.

Comment: @MattPressland [*I'm not demanding anything*]
I'm glad to hear that.
So you don't think a question should be closed *just* because it shows no effort, right? You don't have to bother answering this if the answer is yes.

Comment: @MakotoKato To a good approximation, I do think this - but I do make an individual judgement on each question, and my record of voting to close no-effort questions is not 100%.

Comment: @MattPressland So generally speaking, you do think a question should be closed if it shows no effort.
Could you tell me what kind of no-effort questions are exempted from your close votes?

Comment: @MakotoKato Generally yes. I tend to exclude anything that's wildly outside my area (although now this happens largely because I've hidden the tag so I never see the question at all) or any questions that are essentially pure computation (e.g. evaluate some complicated integral), when I think the context is most likely to be a distraction - it will probably just be the OP attempting the calculation but making a computational rather than conceptual error. Most questions in this second category also fall into the first category for me.

Comment: @Hurkyl "I have been active on another site that did have a more restrictive policy" This must be obvious to everybody except me, but... what is this "other site"? is it still functioning?

Answer (score 14):

I started the close votes on [the question that triggered this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351591/4583), so I'll share my thoughts on it first. When I voted to close, the question consisted of two scans from a book. The first scan had a question of two parts, and the second scan had a proof for the first part of the question. The OP didn't indicate whether they didn't understand the proof they posted or they needed help with the second part. It was difficult to tell what was asked there. This is why I chose "not a real question" as the closing reason.

In general, I do think that we have a problem of low-effort, do-my-homework type of questions. Judging from Stack Overflow and MathOverflow, it seems that closing such questions is the right way to go. When we close a question, we should tell the OP why their question got closed. This would give them a chance to fix the question and try again.

What we need here on MSE is a well-defined policy on what a low-effort homework question is. This isn't an easy task, and I'm not sure we have consensus on this. For now, I do think that ambiguous book scans should fall under this category.

Comment: Just book (or personal, handwritten notes) scans with no further elaboration I just don't look at twice.

Comment: @vonbrand: You could at least do the rest of us a favor and click downvote before moving on. Or at the very least, refrain from trying to dissuade *others* from doing the rest of us a favor!

Comment: @Hurkyl: I disagree utterly. If you don’t want to answer a question, ignore it. Closing it interferes with my freedom to answer it; ignoring it interferes with nothing.

Comment: @Brian: Even if you ignore all of the other concerns -- ignoring the question *does* still *directly* interfere with something: my ability to find the questions  I am interested in.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You can work through or around that minor interference a hell of a lot more easily than someone else can work around a closure.

Comment: @Brian: It's not minor interference. What do we want MSE to be? The things stated in the FAQ? Or an answer service? I want the former. I have been on another site that became much more successful once its moderators decided to stop falling for the "if you don't like it, just ignore it" argument.

Comment: @Hurkyl: As far as I’m concerned it **is** minor interference. I’m reasonably happy with MSE just as it is $-$ or I would be if there were fewer people (a) looking for excuses to close questions and (b) snapping at newcomers.

Comment: @Brian: If someone came here posting a question looking for suggested was to protect one's self from the Wronski Feint, do you think the "if you don't want to answer it, ignore it" argument would hold any water? Your argument only makes sense if we both believe the sort of question under discussion is something that we actually want on the site.

Comment: @Hurkyl, many of these questions *are* among the things we (or many of us, extrapolating from meta conversation and votes) want on the site.  You are in effect demanding that your personal satisfaction or taste be elevated to a site-wide survival criterion for questions. I posted an example in the comments under the question; should that question have been refused, in your opinion?  What about the other one I cited, where there was a coy refusal to answer the WHYT, and then the OP pulled out a complicated and certainly original proof after the answers were in and accepted?

Comment: @Hurkyl: You’re substituting a straw man for my actual position. That hypothetical question is obvious nonsense and can be closed as off-topic, unless it contains a definition of *Wronski Feint* that actually turns it into a meaningful mathematical question. And your last sentence is false: my argument makes sense as long as a significant number of us either want or don’t mind such questions. (Actually, it makes sense to anyone who feels that way, no matter how many or few they are.)

Comment: Prompted by a comment here, now deleted, I checked the top of the users list for fraction of answers in the [homework] tag. I was surprised that my rate of HW answering is half the rate of several of the people complaining about homework-ish postings on meta, and closest to @Hurkyl's rate.  Most other anti-HW folk are generally answering [homework] at a rate consistent with its fraction of all questions.  One interpretation is that homework questions are about as engaging as the rest. If the untagged homework is less mathematically interesting than the tagged, the difference is probably small.

Comment: @zyx: I'm not sure what the last comment means. What's " a rate consistent with its fraction of all questions"? Am I included in your list of anti-HW people? I don't think there are many of those on the site, and you seem to keep confusing anti-HW with "anti-CPHQ with no effort whatsoever shown". That's like confusing all those who support eating meat with mass murderers -- sure, you can do it and to some extent a slippery slope argument shows the two are the same; but it's really just a distortion of the truth.

Comment: How do you know that a question is homework if it's not tagged as homework?

Answer (score 12):

I don't agree with this. I don't think we should close all question without shown effort. Let's look at an recent [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357272/how-can-i-prove-that-xy-leq-x2y2).

Here the OP doesn't show any effort, but some of the 17 (!) answers are absolutely great. If questions like these would be deleted, those 17 answers would never have been written.

I actually like many pages at MSE where the question is some sense bad (no shown effort). Note that such question also invite users to give answers from different "angles". If the OP would have written here, I'm trying to solve this algebraically, and I'm stuck here, then there may be less variation in the given answers.

I do agree that MSE should not be a "do my homework" like website. But I think that closing all question that doesn't show effort is **NOT** the solution. Because I would like to have place at MSE for questions like "here is a nice question, can you show me (different) ways to prove this?" such as the example I have given.

Comment: I think this is an exception, hardly the typical case. I also feel like that question is a duplicate anyway.

Comment: The example you have given does **not** say "here is [a] nice question, can you show me (different) ways to prove this?"

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't thing this is an exception. If I only look at  the questions asked by this user I see many question (no effort shown), but great answers !
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334686/prove-that-the-additive-group-is-not-isomorphic-with-the-multiplicative-grou
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334692/let-s-n-be-a-n-cycle-prove-that-an-element-s-n-only-commutes-with
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328586/examples-of-abelian-subgroups-of-non-abelian-groups
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322993/show-that-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-nxn-0-for-x-in0-1

Comment: I think it would be sad if all those question would have been closed just because the OP doesn't show any effort.

Comment: Then this user is an exception. But wouldn't it be great if the user would write better formulated questions?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think for the OP it would be better, because he/she could have a chance to get some personal tutoring about the concept he/she doesn't understand. But for me? I think I like it that those question are not so "personal", as that invites users to give many different answers. I think the reasons there are so many different (great) answers at some of those questions is actually because the question is so "bad".

Comment: I think it's luck, or coincidence, rather than a particular property of the question. Writing a better formulated question could have included "if there are other ways to see this, I'd be glad to hear them as well".

Comment: @Kasper: I'll see your example and raise you [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349940/if-x-neq-0-y-neq-0-then-x2xyy2-is/)

Answer (score 9):

I'll only adress the issue on which close reason to use. This is an issue for many sites that have some specific rules that are not captured in the network-wide close reasons, e.g. game recommendations on Arqade or the notability requirements on Skeptics. The proper way to handle those is in my opinion:

- Create a Meta post detailing the official policy on these questions and why are closed
- Add a short entry about it in the FAQ
- Close as "off topic"

Using "not a real question" or "not constructive" is just plain wrong in most cases, those questions don't fit the close reason. "Off topic" might be somewhat confusing at first as well, but the scope of the site is something the community can decide, and if the community decides that such assignment dumps without any own effort don't belong on the site, then they are off-topic.

There are some improvements for that in the works at SE, they are currently overhauling the whole close system and rewriting the close rules. From what is known so far, there are some ideas to add site-specific sub-reasons for closing for the "off-topic" reason. This would enable the sites to make their own special rules official directly in the close reasons. But there is no timeframe known on these changes, and we don't know if they will even happen like this.

Comment: This is the only answer to which there are no comments. (Whoops, not any more!)

Answer (score 8):

After metawalking over to [the tex.stackexchange list of canned comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks), I find the ideas they state under `I want to do something very complicated: "Just do it for me"` appealing to this situation.

The core idea, that a question should `revolve around an abstract issue` (e.g. "How do I solve quadratic equations?") rather than a `concrete application` (e.g. "Tell me the roots of $x^2 - x + 2 = 0$."). I believe makes for an excellent summary of crucial points on one side of some aspects of the issue.

(the actual application of this idea there is somewhat different than the situation considered here)

Reflecting on the comments, I'm leaning towards agreeing that closing as "too localized" is the *correct* response.

I believe the main (reasonable) objection boils down to `there's a chance answerers could still give useful responses to the abstract issue making the topic useful to others`.

There is a straightforward response to this objection: even when that actually happens, it's not the question posted that's useful to others: it's the *imagined* question the answerer decided to answer that's useful, *not* the one that was actually asked.

There are numerous benefits to pushing the state of affairs towards one the questions asked are the ones that *can* have useful answers, and where the useful answers are attached to the questions they actually answer.

Comment: I flatly disagree with the notion that a question should ‘revolve around an abstract issue’. And anyone who has actually taught knows the benefit of concrete examples even when abstract issues are involved. You are proposing a limitation that is not just artificial, but counterproductive, and one that would prohibit a great many excellent and interesting questions $-$ clearly stated questions showing thought on the part of the querent $-$ that deal with specific problems.

Comment: At [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) they actually enforce such a rule, but my experience at [tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) suggests they don't actually enforce this ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100232)'s a "Just do it for me"  question of mine with a score of +5).  [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) also have strict rules regarding the quality of questions.

Comment: I am wrestling with this issue.  Even if answerers give an answer that would be useful to others, I think it unlikely the others would find the answer.  There is a huge amount of useful information here.  Many times I know there is the perfect answer to a question, but I can't find it even having read it in the past.  How will somebody who hasn't seen it find it?

Answer (score 6):

In some ways I agree with you, certainly there is a problem with people posting on this site without providing any indication of what they've tried (I don't think anyone would deny that). I'm also fairly confident in saying that this is a **problem** for the site, rather than just an observation. Questions like these waste answerer's time since they have to try and glean the thoughts from the asker. As well as this, it is my opinion that they detract from the overall quality of the site, questions like this tend to be uninteresting, and the answers rarely provide the poster with better understanding, but just... provide an answer. As maths gems points out in a comment above, "there is a wide spectrum of usage of the site" but questions like this aren't good for either of the two extremes described.

However, with all that said, I don't think questions like the one in the link should be closed. I think that allowing questions to be closed because the asker doesn't show  much effort is a dangerous precedent, because it is very subjective to say how much the asker has or hasn't thought about a question.

A lot of the time it may be the case that the asker has thought about the question but doesn't even know where to start. In this case, they would be unable to provide anything showing that they've thought about the question, even if they have.(As Brian M. Scott points out in the comments, it may also be the case that the asker's grasp of English isn't strong enough to provide an explanation of what they have done without a lot of effort.) As well as this, sometimes with questions of the kind described, they aren't actually that hard for someone who has a basic grasp of the material. In this case, no matter how much the asker thinks about the question, they will have nothing to show for it. This is simply because it is not deep enough to get a partial solution and the asker isn't familiar enough with the material to be able to think about it in a worthwhile way. I know I have left a few answers (as comments) along the lines of "Recalling the definition of **thingamie** is **such and such**, applying this to **specific case in question**, can you see how to arrive at the answer?".

To sum up, I don't think that questions like this should be closed. However, I do think that the problem does need addressing, and I also think that this sort of question should not be answered until the asker provides *some* indication that they've done more than copy and paste. I would suggest one approach would be to give more of an indication to new users as they sign up to math.SE of what is expected from their questions. I do agree that it is undesirable to do anything that might scare off new users, but given the number of users who sign up to ask a few low-quality questions and then cease to contribute, I think there is room for some changes to be made.

Comment: I "would deny that" it is necessarily a problem.  We have people who don't indicate what they tried because they are experts asking focused questions; people who do indicate what they tried but it is useless bloat because the efforts are completely off track; and people who are pushed to state what they tried and then nobody comments on those efforts. One guy just posted his own solution to a problem (written before the question) after being pestered, requested evaluation of the work, and received none! If people are not going to utilize the "work" when answering, it should not be requested.

Comment: Also, the interesting/uninteresting nature of the question is mostly independent of "what have they tried", and has to do with subject matter, difficulty, novelty and so on.  The average school homework problems will usually be less interesting than conundrums exchanged between experts, real life applications, or polished competition problems.  Contest problems are, by convention, nearly always stated without hints or prior work, and often in the imperative mood (though of course they *can* be posted with extra information, or de-imperativized, and some people do that).

Comment: *One guy just posted his own solution*... Which post is this?

Comment: The post, which incidentally has a clever WHYT silencer that I hope will be copied by others, is at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341394/prove-that-fracx-nn-is-convergent  (@Did )

Comment: @zyx The original question did not request evaluation of personal work. So this is a two-phase procedure. Phase 1: OP asks "How to prove result R?" and receives answers answering exactly that. Phase 2: later on, OP modifies post, adds own proof of result R and asks "Here is my proof of result R, can you evaluate it?" This seems squarely out of the way the site is supposed to operate, to begin with, because this makes inappropriate every answer posted before phase 2 (and rather illogical to accept any of them, I should add). So, the lesson here might not be the one you try to make us believe.

Comment: @Did, if you read the comments more carefully you will see that the OP had a discussion with the "what have you tried fellow" in which he notified him that this "work" (the OP's proof) had been posted.  It is ridiculous for the WHYT poster, who would have had to see the question again when reading his Inbox, to not read what was posted and respond in some fashion (such as evaluating the proof).  And the OP operated quite consistently with how the site is supposed to function, if there is such a thing at all.

Comment: @zyx I was surprised that you see WHYT comments as "passive-agressive", I certainly never meant them that way. It's exactly would I would say IRL to a student who asked me about a homework problem in a tutorial without indicating that they'd made any effort to think about it at all, although in that case I'd hope it would be clear from my tone of voice that it's a genuine question, rather than a veiled reprimand. It seems this doesn't come across properly when typing it instead.

Comment: @zyx I did read quite carefully, thank you, and what is actually written does not contradict my analysis. (As an aside, I suggest that you stop using derogatory terms to characterize MSE members, their WHYT-comments, or their analyses about the problem of zero-thought-questions, when they do not wish to join you in your crusade.)

Comment: @Did, you should display some examples of derogatory statements about *MSE members* or their *analyses*, especially when you don't seem to consider charming phrases like "zero-thought questions" (or the earlier one to another user about "these Grand Principles of yours" ), or the thousand and one drive-by snarks you are known for in comment threads -- total coincidence that it correlates with champion downvote rate -- as in any way troubling.  If I and others (e.g., the OP) consider WHYT comments to be a negative for the site, the explanation of that will necessarily involve negative concepts.

Comment: @MattPressland, it may be a subject for a separate thread, but to begin with, answering a question with a question, one that is very much used snarkily on the site (e.g., accompanied by explicitly negative continuations like "we are not here to do your homework for you") is not a good starting point.  For most questions where WHYTs are launched, the information is not needed or all that helpful for answering the question, and it is often *not apparently used* by any answerer, and typically not used in any way by those who asked the WHYT.  It is, more often than not, an enforcement ritual.

Comment: Also, having taught a large number of those tutorials, I never found it necessary to ask a student what they had tried.  Students would normally bring their work and want to discuss it. In the rare cases of students who repeatedly had "hidden work" that they did not disclose until the back-and-forth tutorial discussions, I might suggest to reveal the work as it saves time for everyone.  Other than that, there is no need for ontological investigation of what "the work" might be, it is (effectively) whatever is voluntarily put forth without a request. (@MattPressland )

Comment: @zyx Are we witnessing a diversion here? This is not a good sign for the validity of your theses... Maybe this was only to be expected once the post you had invoked to push once again the same agenda, turned out not to support said agenda as much as you thought. O well.

Comment: *A lot of the time it may be the case that the asker has thought about the question but doesn't even know where to start.* It may also be the case that the asker’s command of English (production, as distinct from comprehension) isn’t up to describing partial or failed attempts, at least without inordinate effort.

Comment: Does anybody except @Did seriously dispute the assertion that "we have ... people who are pushed to state what they tried and then nobody comments on those efforts"; that this is a recurring phenomenon; and that it is very likely that someone who posts a WhatHaveYouTried request will not respond (even to say thanks, or at least delete the comment) when that material is posted? Does Did dispute that this pattern is demonstrated in the thread that I cited?  It would seem to be a clear and objective set of facts, but I have learned to never be surprised by what some people will contest online.

Comment: @zyx You are once again diverting the debate... Speaking of "clear and objective set of facts", sorry to stick to the specific case you chose to bring to the fore but how should we interpret the OP's comment "I have posted my original proof, only after receiving a satisfactory answer"? How can "satisfactory" here qualify an answer **which does not address the question** (that is, the question as it is when said comment is posted, but it addresses it as it **was** previously)? Is this whole mess really "consistent" "with how the site is supposed to function"?

Comment: @Did, the OP asked a question, received an answer, and called it satisfactory. Tres bien! He then *also* gave an exhaustive answer to the request to display "what he had tried": an original proof.  I doubt very many people will agree (or recognize some purpose or relevance) in your analysis of why this was a messy abuse of the site, but if you want to extend that long track record of OP-scolding to an $(n+1)$-th intervention, the comment thread at that question is open.  It is also interesting that you call my sticking to the exact point of comment #1, the thing you disputed, a "diversion".

Comment: @zyx While that is often true, I teach tutorials where attendance is compulsory, and students will attend with problem sheets they haven't looked at before they arrive, expecting me to hand out answers. From my point of view, the main point of them being given problem sheets is to make them think about problems (even getting an answer is secondary to spending some time thinking hard about the problem), so my reason for asking is to make sure they aren't skipping that part of the process - often that's what they're trying to do.

Comment: @zyx Obviously you have an infinite amount of time at your disposal to discuss these matters and you are ready to use any and every rhetorical trick to push your very specific agenda. These are two decisive *advantages* in fora such as this one. Hence you win. (Two points: in actual fact, the chronology you give in your last comment is simply false, not by accident. Also it needs some dose of *chutzpah* to mention "scolding" when you are the one who first scolded and rejoiced that a honest commenter was "cleverly" "silenced".) Now, if you shall excuse me from this page, enough is enough...

Comment: @Did, since you were not able to come up with examples of "derogatory remarks" about MSE users, perhaps you could explain this time what you are claiming as rhetorical tricks and deliberate chronology falsification.  As far as I could determine by checking the time stamps, you are kicking up dust about the meaning of the word "then", in relation to events that are *two minutes apart*, and for which my account can be read as being either correct as it is, or as infinitesimally incorrect in ways that make no apparent difference to the discussion.

Comment: It also is not correct to celebrate the WHYT as "honest comments" from "honest commenters".  It is not a form of honesty to make requests for material that one has no interest in seeing, or as a way of fishing for evidence of one's suspicions that the material does not exist. Not all the WHYT comments fit this description, but many do.

Comment: @zyx Sorry but I am not at your service. Anyone interested can read your contributions and decide for themselves what they think of your crusade and of the ways you use to lead it (which, according to me, include intimidations, non sequiturs, and evasions when taken to task for what you actually write about actual specific cases). For the reasons already explained in my last comment, I will not reply to your next comments/orders/fallacies/strange reasonings/whatever. Happy excommunications.

Comment: The Charm Offensive continues its relentless march.  It might occur to you at some point that habitual use of pre-emptive descriptions like *crusade*, *Grand Principles*, *agenda* (repeat $\times n$), *rhetorical trick* and such, are themselves rhetorical games that block discussion.  Telling users of the site -- less frequent than yourself, I might add -- that they spend too much time, and pulling out whenever inconvenient questions are posed, are not good signs either.  Good luck and enjoy the downvoting championship. It is surely unrelated to anything I just wrote. (@Didier.  Did I Err?)

Comment: @Did: zyx’s comments were not a diversion. You’re the one making accusations and refusing (‘I am not at your service’) to back them up. And while zyx is certainly pushing his point of view, you are pushing yours, and **you** are the one using emotionally loaded language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good point about the foreign language angle, I hadn't thought of that. I have edited it into the body of my post.

Comment: I assume it is obvious to some people here but will state it anyway, that the diversion was @Didier's "shoot the OP" deflection of the issue about WhatHaveYouTried (WHYT) commenters, and aggressive demands to follow that detour.  The link showed a sequence of *request,receive,ignore* by the WHYT guy, who was @-notified by OP when the what-OP-tried materials were posted.  Didier assigns negative value to the provision of material (or the timing of such) by the OP, which is strange, but even if correct, a matter between the OP and answerers.  It is orthogonal to issues about WHYT commenters.

Comment: @Tom: Would your opinion on closing being the answer change if, when the question was closed, it was made clear to the asker both *why* it was closed an that it would be easy to reopen once 'e has revised his question?

Comment: @Tom: And what if the policy were limited to the clearest cases, like cphq? Or maybe "cphq" interpreted so strictly as to not even include questions where a person posts their homework then asks "How do I solve this?"

Comment: @Hurkyl Something which I perhaps didn't make very clear is that I do believe that questions where the asker has made no effort should definitely be closed. I am also taking it for granted that if a question was closed, it would have a reason for closing, and conditions for reopening as is the case for any question closed now. The issue I have is that even if the policy was to close only the most obvious offenders, I am sure people will still attempt to close borderline cases or questions that they feel should be closed. Plus, using the review feature, people tend to be quite "close happy".

Comment: I have seen a few questions closed as duplicates for example, when the linked question was not actually a duplicate. Several users, after having seen that the question already had votes to close, simply accepted it as a duplicate and voted to close, without properly checking the link. I fear that this would happen in the "no effort" situation, confusing askers and users seeing the same question closed and re-opened.

Comment: @Tom: Ah, my mistake. One behavioral point to consider is that people are *already* voting to close and delete things (e.g. the question linked in the OP). Without some sort of reasonable group consensus, these efforts will remain ad hoc, and possibly frustrated in motivation. So you need to balance systematizing these efforts through the guidance of (reasonable) official policy against the risk of encouraging new unwanted behavior. (and, I suppose, the benefit of encouraging new *wanted* behavior should be in that consideration too)

Answer (score -2):

> Maybe there should be an official closing reason for this type of questions

If that happens, there should be a complete ban on "What Have You Tried" meta-comments that do nothing except discuss the level of effort, with all such comments flaggable as spam and subject to deletion at any time.

Given direct channels for the WHYT/effort-related signals, including specialized close votes or flags or automated comments that link to an FAQ, the OP has ways to receive all those communications without polluting the environment for the other 99 percent of readers.

Comment: Speaking of which: I presume you're well aware that they already have a WHYT ban over at SO?

Comment: Yes, we were just discussing that ban, and the wisdom of bringing it to MSE, in the comments to a currently active question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/what-have-you-tried   (@J.M.)

Comment: I'm surprised at the downvotes. Maybe they are about the unspoken premise rather than the actual content of this answer? Or maybe the tone? (?!)

Comment: It may be worth noting the difference between somewhat WHYT-like comments that have useful content, such as "have you tried separation of variables" where that is the obvious method, and what is discussed in the answer: *meta-comments that do nothing except discuss the level of effort* (or whether it is homework, or other meta-issues that carry implied criticism and no contribution to balance that).

Answer (score -21):

I don't agree with banning a non-homework question showing no effort.
What if someone asks a question like the Fermat's last theorem without showing no effort? This is an exaggeration, but you get the idea.
Maybe you think that importance of a question is self-evident.
How can you be so sure?

**Edit**
My point is that you could ban important/interesting/useful questions with the policy.

Comment: Please post your opinion explaining the downvote.

Comment: Makoto: First please remember that a downvote on meta just means that someone disagrees with you. And you can probably see all the other answers/comments for reasons for why someone might disagree with you. Second, you of course see some problem-statement-only questions where no one complains. The reason for my asking this specific meta question was that I didn't see any official policy on whether or not one can close a question just because it is statement-only.

Comment: About the FLT question, I would also note that one still can say something about it. Often what is desired is just that the OP gives a little about what they have *tried*. Even with FLT one can *try* things. If one feels that one just fails at every attempt, there might still be something good in the attempt. And besides attempts, one could simply state what *thoughts* one has. Can the OP for example explain what about the problem is causing the most confusion?

Comment: Sorry about the string of comments. Maybe a thing you could do would be to first make clear whether or not you think it is any problem at all when someone just copies down a problem and demands that a solution be given. Is it a problem is math.SE is a place that without hesitation hands out solutions to homework assignments? If you don't think that is a problem, then fine. If you do think it is a problem, then I would like to know what you believe we could do about it. Closing the questions is one obvious way, but maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: @Thomas I'm talking about non-homework questions, okay?
I have no idea what's wrong with borrowing a problem from a textbook and posting it here as long as the OP writes the source.

Comment: So how should we deal with homework questions? (no one is by the way saying it is wrong to "borrow" a problem from a book).

Comment: @Thomas I think they should not be banned.
The reason is the same. A homework question may be important/interesting/useful. You could ban such questions with the policy.
It is not true that every homework is of low level and unimportant.

Comment: No one is saying that we should ban homework questions. I think that you have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @Thomas No, I have not. We are talking about the policy banning a question showing no effort, aren't we?

Comment: @Thomas I correct the above comment as follows: I think homework questions showing no effort should not be banned. The reason is the same. A homework question may be important/interesting/useful. You could ban such questions with the policy. It is not true that every homework is of low level and unimportant.

Comment: You write: "*It is not true that every homework is of low level and unimportant.*" and just to be clear: no one is claiming that.

Comment: I might misunderstand you, so just to to help me understand: Are you saying that you see no problem whatsoever in a student just posting his homework (just the statement) on math.SE expecting to just receive an answer? Is there nothing unethical in a student trying to use math.SE for cheating by having other people do the work? (I am not saying that this is the whole issue, but it is part of it).

Comment: @Thomas `[Are you saying that you see no problem whatsoever in a student just posting his homework (just the statement) on math.SE expecting to just receive an answer?]`

I'm not saying that.
However, if he wants to cheat, he can post the question as non-homework.
He can rewrite the wording and ask the question more politely.
He can also add his effort to the question.
I don't think we can ban it.

Comment: Come now, @MakotoKato. Wanting to cheat on homework is one thing, but deliberately mistagging questions on MSE?  That takes a special flavour of sociopathy. I don't think people like that really exist.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber `[Come now, @MakotoKato. Wanting to cheat on homework is one thing, but deliberately mistagging questions on MSE? That takes a special flavour of sociopathy. I don't think people like that really exist.]`

Come on.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Ok, so we agree that if a person doesn't ask his/her question nicely, but just "demands" an answer, then closing it is acceptable? We of course can't prevent every single person from cheating. Some teacher probably wouldn't even allow their students to seek any help outside office hours. But maybe we can at least close those questions showing no effort written in a demanding way?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber `[Come now, @MakotoKato. Wanting to cheat on homework is one thing, but deliberately mistagging questions on MSE? That takes a special flavour of sociopathy. I don't think people like that really exist.]`
Do you think if someone wants to cheat on homework, he would tag it as homework?

Comment: @Thomas `[@MakotoKato: Ok, so we agree that if a person doesn't ask his/her question nicely, but just "demands" an answer, then closing it is acceptable? We of course can't prevent every single person from cheating. Some teacher probably wouldn't even allow their students to seek any help outside office hours. But maybe we can at least close those questions showing no effort written in a demanding way?]`
I disagree closing a question just because it is not nicely put.
If we would have such a closing policy, we could close (a lot of) important/interesting/useful questions.

Comment: @MakotoKato Alexander Gruber was clearly being sarcastic. You should stop pinging him asking for him to defend a point he wasn't making.

Comment: @AlexBecker `[@MakotoKato Alexander Gruber was clearly being sarcastic.]`
I'm not sure of that.
Anyway, I think the conversation with him on the subject is over.